# Stack Layout OrientationOption end не работает

Tags: c#, android, .net, ios, xamarin

Всем привет, разбираюсь с StackLayout xamarin forms и возник вопрос
почему label не справа, я же задал End? но если сделать StackLayout Orientation Vertical и задать label VerticalOptions end то он будет снизу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предполагаю, что сам `StackLayout` не занимает всю ширину экрана, попробуйте `Background` на него пересадить, чтобы проверить. И вставьте код текстом вместо скриншота, пожалуйста.

Comment: я проверял, всю ширину занимает

Comment: [Вот здесь](https://ericsink.com/entries/xf_measure.html) советуют заменить на `Grid`. Еще пока искал, наткнулся на советы про `FlexLayout`, но сам не знаю разницы.